# JS - Add browser specific prefixes to all CSS transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, phantomjs

I have a set of pages which use CSS transforms to show a variety of content. A lot of this content is generated dynamically and contains CSS `transform`ed elements.
I need it to work on a browser which only supports `-webkit-transform` but not standard `transform`.

Is there any way I can check all the elements for `transform` and add a `-webkit-transform` to them.

**Edit**: I want to do this in a single place, probably in a piece of script that runs after the page has completed rendering.

Comment: Do you have control over the content generated? I presume you scraping pages, right?

Comment: No, I'm not scraping pages. If, by having control you mean owning the page, I'd say yes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check every element. Use feature detection on page load. Something like this:

```js
if (document.body.style.transform != undefined)
{
     // transform
}
else
{
    // -webkit-transform
}
```

Comment: I do not want to change every part of the code. I'm sorry if that was not clear in my question.

Comment: You don't have to. Run this code on page load (listen to the DOMContentLoaded event), and set a variable to true or false. Then you can check this variable in your function and use the prefixed or the standard property.

Comment: It is a good solution and I understand this but the whole of the code is already developed and instead of making changes in all the JS, CSS and plugins I'm looking for a solution that can handle browser specific prefixes in a single place. (Something like what @AminJafari wrote).

Comment: OK, I get it. Although, mine is faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code does an extended version of what you need which I had to implement on one project, it checks if the browser needs any prefixes and sets them on the given properties if needed: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0opf01aj/1/)**

```
var vendors = [
    '-webkit-',
    '-o-',
    '-moz-',
    '-ms-',
    ''
];

function toCamelCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, function($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase().replace('-', '');
    });
}

function getSupportedProp(proparray) {
    var root = document.documentElement,
        rootStyle = root.style;
    for (var i = 0, proparrayLength = proparray.length; i < proparrayLength; i++) {
        if (proparray[i] in rootStyle) {
            return proparray[i];
        }
    }
}

function setProp(prop){
    var propArray = [];
  for(var i=0, vendorsLength=vendors.length; i < vendorsLength; i++){
    var vendor=vendors[i];
    propArray.push(toCamelCase(vendor + prop));
  };
  var prefixedProp = getSupportedProp(propArray);

  document.body.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(elem,index){
    var value=window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(prop);
    elem.style[prefixedProp] = value;
  });
}

setProp('transform');
```

Comment: Awesome. That really looks like what I was thinking when I thought of going all bruteforce on the problem. Although I am not sure if I would be able to see the effects in a normal (new) browser.

Comment: that's right, you gotta test it on some old browsers :)